# Memory issue in Java

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I've a multi-threaded program which deals with lots of String manipulations and after few hrs of executions the memory exceeds and cause the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" issue. And I've already utilized my whole memory to the java program i.e.  16 GB.

For the test I've created following sample program to understand the issue and its doing the same issue, after just re-initializing a string builder few thousand times it consumes more than 5-10MB of memory, can anyone pls help to overcome this issue.

```
StringBuilder strObj = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<50000; i++) {
    strObj = null;
    strObj = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Comment: this code will only cause an OOME if you are out-running the GC.  otherwise, all the old instances are lost and will be garbage collected.  in other words, in normal usage, this code will not cause any memory problems.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - make garbage faster than the GC can clean it.  at some point the GC gives up and throws OOME, even though there may theoretically be more space available.  why does that sound so far fetched to you?  a GC is just another algorithm with trade-offs, it is not some sort of "perfect" garbage re-claiming system.

Comment: @jtahlborn GC may have a lot of trade-offs, but this simply isn't one of them. Even the ConcurrentMarkSweep, the most concurrent version of GC available on the HotSpot, will **stop the world** and do a major GC before OOME. Also, each minor collection is **always** of the stop-the-world flavor.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - apparently you've never gotten an OOME "GC overhead limit exceeded".  i'm not sure why you seem to think the GC has such powers of "super-perfect-garbage-collection" (hint, it doesn't).  And i'm not sure what "stopping the world" has to do with anything?

Comment: @jtahlborn Indeed I got that exception and it is unrelated. It happens when you are running close to full memory, but the GC is just barely making it everytime it runs. The system slows down to a crawl due to constant major GC cycles, whose CPU time begins to drown out any meaningful computation. Try getting that exception with a clean heap and just generating an infinite amount of short-lived objects (like in OP's code sample).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - i agree that it would be virtually impossible for the OP's example to out-run the GC, however i was addressing your question where you seemed to have never heard of the concept: "Never heard of such a thing".

Comment: @jtahlborn Well, "outrunning the GC" is at least a misleading phrase to describe the conditions under which the OOME due to GC overhead happens. It sounds like "just make sure not to be too fast with your garbage, you'll *outrun the Java Garbage Truck*!"

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - actually, that's exactly what i meant.  while the average program may not cause it to happen, it certainly can happen, and not just in the conditions you described.

Comment: In every case that happens, it **does not** happen because you are *outrunning the GC*, but because you are so low on memory that the only way to satisfy your ongoing allocation requests is to purge every last byte of the heap. Even in those conditions the GC is still not getting outrun: **every reclaimable byte of the heap is being reclaimed**, but the ratio of useful work to GC work degrades.

Answer (score 1):

In what sense does it consume 5-10MB of memory? you're allocating that much here. Java is not going to bother reclaiming it until it needs memory. This can't be causing `OutOfMemoryError`, not this type of code.

So, why not actually show the kind of code that is causing the OOME?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support guys, actually my problem was resolved after garbage collecting manually by calling **System.gc()** statement.

Comment: Exactly; without that you'll notice that the heap occupancy creeps towards the young generation size limit, then suddenly drops to empty, this cycle repeating forever.